# Linker problems in C++ template

Tags: templates, visual-c++, linker

I have a function template in a .h file , which is included in my main file and used to create an Excel chart. If I write the template function as a non-template method, then all is well. When I make the function a function template I get many unresolved external symbol errors for the calls within the function template to methods in the Excel namespace. This is all in Visual Studio 2010 by the way.

As an example, if in myFunc.h I have

```
template<class T> 
void ExcelGraph(const std::vector<T>& xData){
//Calls to the various methods in the Excel namespace
}
```

and in main.cpp

```
 #include"myFunc.h"

 int main(){
 std::vector<float> xData(100,1);
 ExcelGraph(xData);
 }
```

then the code will generate linker errors. If myFunc.h looks likes this:

```
void ExcelGraph(const std::vector<float>& xData){
//Calls to the various methods in the Excel namespace
}
```

and in main.cpp

```
 #include"myFunc.h"

 int main(){
 std::vector<float> xData(100,1);
 ExcelGraph(xData);
 }
```

Then the code compiles and runs just fine.

There are too many linker errors to post, but they're all of the form

`1>Excel_Interface_Test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Excel::_Chart::PutName(class _bstr_t)" (?PutName@_Chart@Excel@@QAEXV_bstr_t@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl ExcelPlotting::ExcelGraph<float>(class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> > const &,class std::vector<float,class std::allocator<float> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (??$ExcelGraph@M@ExcelPlotting@@YAXABV?$vector@MV?$allocator@M@std@@@std@@V12@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@22@Z)`

Comment: Can we perhaps see the linker errors? I suspect (near-certain, actually) that you're being passed a temp-copy of that vector in the second example.

Comment: I've added a sample of the error to the main post.

Comment: Does this error correspond to what you thought @WhozCraig?

Comment: The errors are coming from your Excel namespace symbols not being linked (at least that is what it looks like). There is nothing immediately wrong that I see with the *code* ([see it live and simple](http://ideone.com/JrofvG)). I also don't see how the second snippet, `std::vector xData(100,1);` can even *compile*.

Comment: My bad, there's obviously a typename declaration, the two versions of main.cpp are actually identical. I've edited the first post

Comment: I still can't understand how the Excel namespace gets linked correctly when I don't use a template, but fails when I do.

Comment: If you have `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` in your source, try adding the needed library to the project instead.